# Google Maps search box with dragable marker and input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps api and need to show a marker with a search box, this marker will use the lat and long I have on my database but will change if dragged or someone uses the search box. I managed to load the map and center it on the coordinates but it doesn’t shows the marker, after I use the search box all works.
I tried adding a marker in the beginning of the code but without success, it creates a new marker when I used the functions:

```
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: LatLng,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }    

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
    var latitude = ;
    var longitude = ;
    var zoom = "+MapZoom+";

    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.501476, ‎-0.140634);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        map: map,
        title: '"+Latitude+"',
        draggable: true
    });
```

This is my current code, I’m sure I’m just missing something any help would be much appreciated

```
function initialize() {

var markers = [];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(51.501476, ‎-0.140634));
    map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);
var input = (document.getElementById('pacinput')
);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
if (places.length == 0) {
  return;
}
for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
  marker.setMap(null);
}
markers = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,

    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  // drag response
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
    displayPosition(this.getPosition());
  });
  // click response
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
    displayPosition(this.getPosition());
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
var bounds = map.getBounds();
searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
});
// displays a position on two <input> elements
function displayPosition(pos) {
document.getElementById('Latitude').value = pos.lat();
document.getElementById('Longitude').value = pos.lng();
}
}  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
initialize();
</script>"
```

Comment: your question still seems unclear can you elaborate?

Comment: Of course, I used the example in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder but I want it to work with only one marker.  Onload of the page the script zooms on that lat and long that I have for my input fields but won’t show a marker that I can drag and drop.
the marker only shows after using the search box, but I need it on initializing. Let me know if it helps and thanks in advance for looking in to it.

Comment: Your code contains an invalid bounds: `var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng("+Latitude+", "+Longitude+"));`, this `map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);` doesn't work.

Comment: That is how my IDE passes the values in the script. I have changed it to some random values. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**as per my understanding you want marker on load of page to the same location where your map is centered try using this**

```
var map;
var marker;
$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
    drawmarker();
    darggable();
});

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);


}
function drawmarker(){
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
        title:"this s it",
        map : map,
        draggable:true,
    })
}
```

**make your marker as global now use method on dragend**

```
function darggable(){
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
                console.log(e.latLng.lat(),e.latLng.lng())

              });
}
```

**now you get the latlng now use it to display in the text box**

Comment: Its almost this, but this marker isnt linked to my elements(
'Latitude' and 'Longitude') so when i drag it around or use the search box for places it doesnt update the values

Comment: i did not understand what do you mean by linked

Comment: I created a fiddle that should explain the issue https://jsfiddle.net/poL8udm9/4/ 
The issue is that when you drag and drop the first marker it doesnt update the input boxes, but if use the search box and drag and drop the new marker it updates the lat and lng